# Variable data on pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add variable text and thumbnail images on specific position.
Text with formatting like fontstyles,rotation etc.

```
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
     Document document = new Document();
                   PdfWriter writer;
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,
                       new FileStream(temp,
                       FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
 reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file);
                               size = reader.GetCropBox(1);

                   PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                   document.NewPage();
                   PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader,
                   pageNumber);
                   cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                   document.Close();
```

This will copy first page to new document. I want to add text and images on new document. how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people will stop reading your question after your first sentence:

> I want to Edit existing PDF

If you read the intro of [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf), you'll understand that the word *Edit* is not the right word to use.

I *did* read on, and that I saw that you were using `Document` and `PdfWriter` to stamp new content on an existing PDF. If you do the effort of reading chapter 6 of my book, you'll understand that **this is wrong**. You should use `PdfStamper` instead.

This is one of the examples provided online:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Phrase header = new Phrase("Copy", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14));
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        float x = reader.getPageSize(i).getWidth() / 2;
        float y = reader.getPageSize(i).getTop(20);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(
            stamper.getOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            header, x, y, 0);
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

You can find these examples on the following URLs:

- http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper
- http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=6

If you need the examples from chapter 6 ported to C#, please visit this URL: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06

**Update**

Does `PdfStamper` support:

- font embedding: yes, when done correctly, fonts are embedded,
- font size: yes, that's obvious,
- font family: you provide the font program, the font program knows the font family,
- alignments: for single lines: use `showTextAligned()`; for text blocks use `ColumnText` (**caveat:** read about the difference between *text mode* and *composite mode*)
- rotation: for single lines, this is only a matter of providing a rotation angle; for text blocks, create a Form XObject and add this object using a rotation,
- ...

Comment: Is Stamper provide all the text formatting options like font embedding, size,color,family,alignments,rotation etc?

Comment: That's a strange question. Did you try? What didn't work? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I've updated my answer in spite of the fact that your extra question in the comments is too broad.

Comment: Yes many Thanks for your support, will try this out.. I was using some other library, that Cannot handle iref streams with arobat 6 pdf documents.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: `iref` is probably a typo. You probably meant to write `xref` streams. These were introduce in PDF 1.5 and you are right: not all PDF libraries can read PDFs that use compressed objects and compressed cross-reference tables.